# Multiple "s in ASP statement

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datagrid, datarow

I am databinding some SQL to a GridView and now want to have a link to a javascript function with 2 parameters, one being another field in the row.

```
NavigateUrl="javascript:ShowDialogTest('2','<% ((DataRow)Container.DataItem)["SQLItem"] %>')" />
```

However I cannot get the SQLItem in double quotes because it thinks it's the end of the NavigateURL. I also cannot have single quotes because it then stops the parameter.

Not sure how I get about this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple workaround would be to bind the `NavigateUrl` property from code behind, in the `OnItemDataBound`event.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Francis's answer, that's a good approach.  You could also use the integer index value instead of the name indexer, if you wanted to avoid tapping into `OnItemDataBound`.

```
"javascript:ShowDialogTest('2','<% ((DataRow)Container.DataItem)[1] %>')"
```